# Servlet: HTTP Status 404 - /Test/SimpleServletPath

Tags: java, servlets

I have created a small dynamic web project to understand the mechanism of the Java Servlet but when I run the `SimpleServlet` on server I am getting the `HTTP Status 404` error but when typing this url `http://localhost:8082/Test/` I am getting the content of the index.html file rendered. I dont have a web.xml file.
How can I run the servlet on the server?

**SimpleServlet**

```
package org.user;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(description = "A simple servlet", urlPatterns = { "/SimpleServletPath" })
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        // To use the username in different browser.
        ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();

        if (userName != null && !userName.isEmpty()) {

            session.setAttribute("savedNameUser", userName);
            context.setAttribute("savedNameUser", userName);

        }

        writer.println("Request parameter has username as  " + userName
                + "</br>");

        writer.println("Session parameter has username as  "
                + (String) session.getAttribute("savedNameUser") + "</br>");

        writer.println("Context parameter has username as  "
                + (String) context.getAttribute("savedNameUser"));

    }
}
```

**image**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by run the servlet?  Where are the input parameters you're trying to display coming from?

Comment: You are using Eclipse so it is impossible that you do not have a web.xml file. Check your WEB-INF folder thoroughly.

Comment: If your container supports latest j2ee specs, a web.xml is not necessary.

Comment: I do not know what was the reson for this error but after changing the workspace directory of eclipse it workd again.

Comment: Please write the solution so this question isn't continually being looked at to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution but it worked for me. I had to change the eclipse workspace directory and built the project again. Then I tried it in the new project with the same servlet and worked for me.